# Möbius function on a finite poset (X, $\leq$)

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, multiplicative-function, mobius-function

I'm having some difficulties with the following problem:

> Give an example of a finite poset $(X, \leq)$ and elements $a,b \in$ X such that $\mu(a,b)=-4$ where $\mu$ is the Möbius function of $(X, \leq)$.

I think I know what a finite poset $(X, \leq)$ typically looks like, but how does this Möbius function come into play? My understanding of Möbius functions is mainly limited to recurrences and matrices, so I don't know how this generally changes things.

Comment: The Moebius function does not *alter* a poset in any way. Your understanding of Moebius functions sounds very strange; you should probably read up a bit of some textbook, like Stanley's great *Enumerative Combinanorics*, volume 1.

Comment: I suspect you are confusing Möbius functions with Möbius transformations. They are quite different.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, that is immensely unlikely, given what is written in the post.

Comment: There's enough information in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_algebra) for you at least to verify Mariano's example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple example is the following:

[image]

Comment: What program / language did you use to create this Hasse diagram? It is very nice.